# Can an ASP.Net page implement an interface without using a codebehind page?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, vb.net

I have an ASP.Net page that needs to implement an interface class I've created, but since  the code in this page is inline, there's no class declaration, and therefore no place to put the "Implements IMyInterface" line. I also tried using the @interface page directive but it appears this only works for built in .Net framework classes.

Are there any options other than using a codebehind page just to edit the class declaration line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do it with an Implements directive:

```
<%@ Implements Interface="MyNamespace.IMyInterface"  %>
```

Comment: Got it working. Turns out I was using the wrong namespace. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

I dont think so.  You can specify the base class though using the inherits directive.  You can the have a class that derives from Page and implement the interface in this class.